# Cakephp 3.0 having error when running phpunit testcase from book

Tags: phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I already installed phpunit but im still having an error when running **phpunit tests/TestCase/Model/Table/ArticlesTableTest**

My test model and controller are generated from cake bake command

I followed this guide from their documentation 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html

This is what i get from the console

```
There were 2 errors:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\ArticlesTableTest::testInitialize
Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource confi
guration "default" was not found.

D:\web\xampp\htdocs\test\cakeblog-test\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasourc
e\ConnectionManager.php:187
D:\web\xampp\htdocs\test\cakeblog-test\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table
Registry.php:191
D:\web\xampp\htdocs\test\cakeblog-test\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\PersonTab
leTest.php:32
```

Comment: Well, the error message seems pretty straight forward. Have you checked whether a `default` connection is present in your app config?

Comment: I added this in config/app.php in Datasources

'test' => [
        'datasource' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'myUserName',
        'password' => 'myPassword',
        'database' => 'test_database'
    ],

Comment: So in other words, there is no `default` connection?

Comment: I already have **default** and **test** datasource connection in my config/app.php that came from config/app.default.php and is currently working when accessing http://localhost/mycake-app/. But im still having an error when i run **phpunit tests/TestCase/Model/Table/ArticlesTableTest**

Comment: Can you show your phpunit.xml file?

Comment: phpunit.xml found in vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/build/<br/>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="../tests/bootstrap.php"
         verbode="true">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="php-token-stream">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">../tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>

  <filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
      <directory suffix=".php">../src</directory>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
</phpunit>

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error. The problem for me was in the Command prompt, when I run my tests in PowerShell everything was Ok.
If you are using Windows try run your tests in the PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800709/cakephp-3-missingdatasourceconfigexception-when-running-phpunit-test).**

I had the same problem using Ubuntu 14.04 (no PowerShell here). In my case the problem was that I was running the tests from a wrong location. According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#running-tests) you need to be **standing in your app root's folder** to correctly run your tests.

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/app
$ vendor/bin/phpunit tests/TestCase/Model/Table/ArticlesTable
```