# Cakephp 3 - MissingDatasourceConfigException when running phpunit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to run some unit tests in CakePHP 3 with PHPUnit 4.7.3, but I`m getting the following error:

```
PHPUnit 4.7.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

There was 1 error:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\MoviesTableTest::testFindMoviesByGenre
Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource configuration "default" was not found.

C:\xampp\htdocs\movie-pal\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\ConnectionManager.php:188
C:\xampp\htdocs\movie-pal\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\TableRegistry.php:191
C:\xampp\htdocs\movie-pal\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\MoviesTableTest.php:17

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I have tried to follow the book, but probably I`m missing something.

In the app.php I have:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'movies',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    ],
    'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'test_movies',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    ],
],
```

My test class:

```
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Table\MoviesTable;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

class MoviesTableTest extends TestCase
{
    public $fixtures = ['app.movies'];

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Movies = TableRegistry::get('Movies');
    }

    public function testFindMoviesByGenre()
    {
       .......
    }

}
```

phpunit.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
  colors="true"
  processIsolation="false"
  stopOnFailure="false"
  syntaxCheck="false"
  bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php"
  >
  <php>
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
  </php>

  <!-- Add any additional test suites you want to run here -->
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="App Test Suite">
      <directory>./tests/TestCase</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <!-- Add plugin test suites here. -->
  </testsuites>

  <!-- Setup a listener for fixtures -->
  <listeners>
    <listener
    class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector"
    file="./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php">
      <arguments>
        <object class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureManager" />
      </arguments>
    </listener>
  </listeners>

</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Command prompt, when I run my tests in Windows PowerShell everything was OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Ubuntu 14.04 (no PowerShell here). In my case the problem was that I was running the tests from a wrong location. According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#running-tests) you need to be **standing in your app root's folder** to correctly run your tests.

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/app
$ vendor/bin/phpunit tests/TestCase/Model/Table/MoviesTable
```